# Duplicate key error when saving a new user

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save a User and a Profile in django which are linked together using a `oneToOneField` but I'm getting an error saying

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "auth_user_username_key

eventhough I dont have any duplicates.

I also get this error:

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "api_profile_user_id_key" DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(9) already exists.

Here is my code:

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import CharField, OneToOneField
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = CharField(max_length=20)
    account_type = CharField(max_length=10, default='basic')
    facebook_id = CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    google_id = CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    notification_id = CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    # TODO add account info and watchlist

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

**view.py:**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def sign_up(request):
    data = request.data
    user = User.objects.create_user(username=data['username'],
                                    password=data['password'],
                                    first_name=data['first_name'],
                                    last_name=data['last_name'],
                                    email=data['email']
                                    )
    user.profile.phone_number = data['phone_number']
    user.save()
    return Response('hey')
```

I think the problem is in the post_save receiver however I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`create_user` is also calling save(), then you also call `user.save()`, the post_save signal is being called twice for one user, you get the error because two Profile objects are being created for one user

You could do:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right as it queries the database for something that should be known in the code. I added a third parameter `created` in the function and I only create only if the flag is true. This seems to have fixed it